# Creating a edge tile with modifiers

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to create a edge for a wall. I'd like to use modifiers on the straight parts to form the edge. I'm using tilable objects. The edge is 1x1 and the straight parts are 2 units in length. This is how it should look like, which I created by hand:

[image]

This is how I tried to replicate it with a SimpleDeform modifier. I also tried a Lattice and the spin tool but did not manage to solve it so far.

[image]

I also want to bend the edge this way:

[image]

How do I archive this? What modifiers should I use? I'm aware that the edge will get stretched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did manage to do it with a Curve modifer and a SimpleDeform (stretch) modifer. But this is not "pixel" perfect. Still open to other suggestions.

[image]